# App Store screenshots looks blurry on iPad... Whats going on?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I'm following the Apple's guideline to make the screenshots needed for an app.
The thing is that no matter what I do inside the accepted variations, the screenshots
are being displayed with a little blur in the app store when browsing via iPad, but in the web store the look fine.

After some observations and research, this is not happening to my screenshots only, there are a lot of apps that suffer the same issue and the common factor seems to be: letters. When screenshots only display graphics or photos they look fine everywhere, but if your screenshots involves, i.e.: a simple table with text, the blurry effect appears.

Any ideas how can I avoid this? Anybody knows any details about how this screenshots are treated by apple to make the store versions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume you're checking this over WiFi on the iPad - our local 3G provider proxies all the requests and reduces the quality of images to make downloads smaller

Comment: This is not a programming question. You'd do better to ask this in an Apple developer forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the screen shot yourself (pressing Home button and Power button at same time). Then email yourself the photos and upload through iTunes Connect. I use a tableview for one of my app screenshots and it comes out looking fine.